Comparison of centred and uncentred Hardy-Littlewood maximal functions in doubling measure
From the definition of a doubling measure on wikipedia:
"A measure on a metric space $X$ is said to be doubling if the measure of any ball is approximately the measure of its double, or more precisely, if there is a constant $C > 0$ such that
$\mu(B(x,2r))\leq C\mu(B(x,r))$
for all $x \in X$ and $r > 0$.
Let $(X,d,\mu)$ be a doubling metric measure space.
Consider the centered Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator
$$ \mathcal{M}f(x):= \sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)| \text{d}\mu(y) $$
and the uncentered
$$ Mf(x):= \sup_{r>0, d(y,x)<r} \frac{1}{\mu(B(y,r))} \int_{B(y,r)} |f(t)| \text{d} \mu(t). $$
I want to show
$$ Mf(x) \leq C \mathcal{M}f(x).$$
My attempt is:
For any $y$ such that $d(y,x) < r$, we have $B(y,r) \subset B(x,2r)$. Thus, for such $y$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\mu(B(y,r))} \int_{B(y,r)} |f(t)| \, d\mu(t) 
&\le \frac{1}{\mu(B(y,r))} \int_{B(x,2r)} |f(t)| \, d\mu(t) \\
&= \frac{\mu(B(x,2r))}{\mu(B(y,r))} \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,2r))}\int_{B(x,2r)} |f(t)| \, d\mu(t) \\
&\le \frac{\mu(B(x,2r))}{\mu(B(y,r))}\mathcal{M}f(x).
\end{align}
Unfortunately i couldn't estimate $\frac{\mu(B(x,2r))}{\mu(B(y,r))}$. I should use doubling condition but balls' centers are different. I'm confused at this point. Can you help me?

Perhaps you could apply the doubling condition $k$ times until $B(x,2^{1-k}r)\subseteq B(y,r)$? Not sure if it leads anywhere though.

The caveat is that you have to use a different constant.
Use $B(x, 4r)$ and $B(y, 2r)$ instead. Then denoting by $C$ the doubling constant,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\mu(B(y,r))} \int_{B(y,r)} |f(t)| \, d\mu(t) 
&\le \frac{C}{\mu(B(y,2r))} \int_{B(x,4r)} |f(t)| \, d\mu(t) \\
&= C \frac{\mu(B(x,4r))}{\mu(B(y,2r))} \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,4r))}\int_{B(x,4r)} |f(t)| \, d\mu(t) \\
&\le C\frac{\mu(B(x,4r))}{\mu(B(x,r))}\mathcal{M}f(x). \\
&\le C^3 \mathcal M f(x)
= C’ \mathcal M f(x),
\end{align}
with $ C’ := C^3$ as desired.
In going from the second to third line, we have used that $B(x, r) \subset B(y, 2r)$, and so $\mu(B(x, r)) \leq \mu (B(y, 2r))$.
